# How to remove the black sprite in the middle of my screen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

I have a maze game that comprises of 3 different class, which includes 2 maze solving algorithms and a class for players to move around with the up, down, left and right key. So the way to toggle between the classes is to use a tab key. But however, when i reach the class where users can manually control the sprite, there will always be a random black arrow that looks like its going through spasm in the middle of my window. Even though i can manage to control the orange sprite, but that black arrow is still there. Is there anyway that i can remove it? I tried using `hideturtle` to hide the arrow, but to no avail.

I highly suspect that it was due to this part of my code that resulted in the appearance of the black arrowhead. But i wasn't able to find a replacement for that.

```py
while True:
    ManualMovements()
```

This is how the black sprite looks like right now:
[image]

My current code:

```py
from turtle import * # import the turtle library

# define the tile_size and cursor_size for usage later on
TILE_SIZE = 24 
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

screen = Screen() # instantiate the Screen class from turtle
screen.setup(700, 700) # determine the size of the turtle pop out window

class Wall(Turtle): # create Wall class to plot out the walls
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() # inherit from Turtle(parent class)
        self.hideturtle() # hide the cursor
        self.shape('square') # define the shape of the object we wanna draw out
        self.shapesize(TILE_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE) # define the size of the square
        self.pencolor('black') #  define the color that we are going to plot the grids out
        self.penup() # to prevent the pen from leaving a trace
        self.speed('fastest') # get the fastest speed

class Path(Turtle): # create Path class to plot out the path
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() # inherit from Turtle(parent class)
        self.hideturtle() # hide the cursor
        self.shape('square') # define the shape of the object we wanna draw out
        self.shapesize(TILE_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE) # define the size of the square
        self.pencolor('white') #  define the color that we are going to plot the grids out
        self.penup() # to prevent the pen from leaving a trace
        self.speed('fastest') # get the fastest speed

class Sprite(Turtle): # create Sprite class to define the turtle and its characteristics
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() # inherit from Turtle(parent class)
        self.shape('turtle') # define the shape of the object we wanna draw out
        self.shapesize((TILE_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)-0.4) # define the size of the square
        self.color('orange') #  define the color that we are going to plot the turtle
        self.penup() # to prevent the pen from leaving a trace
        self.speed('slowest') # set speed to slowest to observe the sprite movement

class ManualMovements(Sprite): # create ManualMovement class to let the user manually control the sprite
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.moves = 0
        self.hideturtle()
        self.screen.onkeypress(self.go_up, "Up")
        self.screen.onkeypress(self.go_down, "Down")
        self.screen.onkeypress(self.go_left, "Left")
        self.screen.onkeypress(self.go_right, "Right")

    def go_up(self):
        xcor = sprite.xcor()
        ycor = sprite.ycor()

        if (xcor, ycor + TILE_SIZE) not in walls:
            sprite.setheading(90)
            sprite.goto(xcor, ycor + TILE_SIZE)

    def go_down(self):
        xcor = sprite.xcor()
        ycor = sprite.ycor()

        if (xcor, ycor - TILE_SIZE) not in walls:
            sprite.setheading(270)
            sprite.goto(xcor, ycor - TILE_SIZE)

    def go_left(self):
        xcor = sprite.xcor()
        ycor = sprite.ycor()

        if (xcor - TILE_SIZE, ycor) not in walls:
            sprite.setheading(180)
            sprite.goto(xcor - TILE_SIZE, ycor)

    def go_right(self):
        xcor = sprite.xcor()
        ycor = sprite.ycor()

        if (xcor + TILE_SIZE, ycor) not in walls:
            sprite.setheading(0)
            sprite.goto(xcor + TILE_SIZE, ycor)

def setup_maze(level): # create a setup_maze function so that we can plot out the map in turtle
    # declare maze_height and maze_width first as the limits for the entire maze
    maze_height, maze_width = len(level), len(level[0])

    # get the center point for each maze
    center_horizontal_point = (maze_width + 1) / 2
    center_vertical_point = (maze_height + 1) / 2    

    for y in range(maze_height): # for loop to limit the entire maze
        for x in range(maze_width):
            character = level[y][x] # get the character at each x,y coordinate

            # calculate the screen x, y coordinates
            screen_x = ((x - maze_width) * TILE_SIZE) + (center_horizontal_point * TILE_SIZE)
            screen_y = ((maze_height - y) * TILE_SIZE) - (center_vertical_point * TILE_SIZE)

            if character == "X":
                maze.fillcolor('grey')
                maze.goto(screen_x, screen_y)
                maze.stamp()
                walls.append((screen_x, screen_y)) # add coordinates for the wall to the list
            else:
                maze.fillcolor('white')
                maze.goto(screen_x, screen_y)
                maze.stamp()
                paths.append((screen_x, screen_y)) # add coordinates for the path to the list

            if character == "e":
                maze.fillcolor(['white', 'red'][character == 'e'])
                maze.goto(screen_x, screen_y) # proceed on to the coordinates on turtle
                maze.stamp() # stamp out the boxes
                finish.append((screen_x, screen_y)) # add coordinates for the endpoint to the list             

            if character == 's': # if statement to determine if the character is s
                maze.fillcolor('green')
                maze.goto(screen_x, screen_y)
                maze.stamp() # stamp out the boxes
                start.append((screen_x, screen_y)) # add coordinates for the startpoint to the list
                sprite.goto(screen_x, screen_y) # move the sprite to the location where it is supposed to start

def endProgram(): # exit the entire program upon clicking anywhere in the turtle window
    screen.exitonclick()

grid = []                               # create a grid list to store the labels while reading from the txt file
walls = []                              # create walls coordinate list
start = []
finish = []                             # enable the finish array
paths = []
maze = Wall()                           # enable the Wall class
sprite = Sprite()                       # enable the Sprite class
path = Path() 

with open("map02.txt") as file:         # open the txt file and read contents and append it to maze
    for line in file:
        grid.append(line.strip())

setup_maze(grid)                        # call the setup maze function

start_x, start_y = (start[0])[0], (start[0])[1]

sprite.seth(0)
sprite.goto(start_x, start_y)

while True:
    ManualMovements()

screen.listen() # we need this in order to allow turtle to detect what key we are pressing and respond to it
screen.mainloop()
```

A sample txt file map:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Xe.................X
XXXXXXX...X..XXXXX.X
XXXXXX....X.....XXXX
XXX.......X...X.XXXX
XXXXXX....X.....XXXX
X.........X...XXXXXX
X.XXXXXX..X...XXXXXX
X.X.......X..XXXXXXX
X.X...XXXX.........X
X.XXXXXsXX..XXXXXXXX
X..............XXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

**EDIT: Some edits have been made. Please relook again. In order to execute the code, you have to press tab once before pressing the up, down, left, right buttons from my side. I also have removed the 2 classes to prevent confusion and also since i pinpointed that this part of the code is where my error should come from. The current code above does replicate the same error too.**

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see any strange black sprite... I see white squares, grey squares, one red, and one green/yelllow one, and one white square with a black arrow in it. Only the tile separations are thin black lines. Is the arrow what you mean?

Comment: err ye the arrow is what im referring to. I made the edit to my question already. Thanks for the pointout!

Comment: you don't have all of your code here, and there's nothing in this code that would display the arrow. ofc if you knew what section of the code to show in this question you wouldn't have the question but you can try showing more of your code

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite hi, i've remodified the codes with the relevent parts  already.

Comment: Reproducible problem; it switches between the arrow and a turtle sprite. Random observation: If you press an arrow for a long time, the turtle moves through walls and even leaves the field, then moves in steps backwards - during these back steps, the arrow disappears.

Comment: @Mr.T It also depends on when u start to press the arrow for a long time. Sometimes, it becomes a yellow turtle, and sometimes it becomes a black turtle, which is the baffling part.

Comment: Ninja turtle. Goes through walls. Camouflages in black. Not baffling at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `ManualMovements` class is wrong-headed.  Rather than a bizarre *helper* class, it should be a subclass of `Sprite`.  (Akin to a fully automated Sprite subclass.)  I've reworked your code accordingly below as well as made other fixes and optimizations -- pick and choose as you see fit:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

# define some global constants for use later
TILE_SIZE = 24
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

class Wall(Turtle):
    ''' class to plot out walls '''

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(shape='square')  # inherit from parent class

        self.hideturtle()
        self.shapesize(TILE_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)  # define the size of the square
        self.penup()  # prevent the pen from leaving a trace
        self.speed('fastest')

class Path(Wall):
    ''' class to plot out the path '''

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # inherit from parent class

        self.pencolor('white')  # define the color that we are going to plot the grids out

class Sprite(Turtle):
    ''' class to define turtle sprite and its characteristics '''

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(shape='turtle')  # inherit from parent class

        self.shapesize((TILE_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE) - 0.4)  # define the size of the square
        self.color('orange')  # color that we are going to plot the turtle
        self.penup()  # prevent the pen from leaving a trace
        self.speed('slowest')  # set speed to slowest to observe the sprite movement

class ManualSprite(Sprite):
    ''' class to let the user manually control the sprite '''

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        screen.onkeypress(self.go_up, 'Up')
        screen.onkeypress(self.go_down, 'Down')
        screen.onkeypress(self.go_left, 'Left')
        screen.onkeypress(self.go_right, 'Right')

    def go_up(self):
        screen.onkeypress(None, 'Up')  # disable handler inside handler

        xcor = int(self.xcor())
        ycor = int(self.ycor())

        if (xcor, ycor + TILE_SIZE) not in walls:
            self.setheading(90)
            self.sety(ycor + TILE_SIZE)

        screen.onkeypress(self.go_up, 'Up')  # reenable handler on exit

    def go_down(self):
        screen.onkeypress(None, 'Down')

        xcor = int(self.xcor())
        ycor = int(self.ycor())

        if (xcor, ycor - TILE_SIZE) not in walls:
            self.setheading(270)
            self.sety(ycor - TILE_SIZE)

        screen.onkeypress(self.go_down, 'Down')

    def go_left(self):
        screen.onkeypress(None, 'Left')

        xcor = int(self.xcor())
        ycor = int(self.ycor())

        if (xcor - TILE_SIZE, ycor) not in walls:
            self.setheading(180)
            self.setx(xcor - TILE_SIZE)

        screen.onkeypress(self.go_left, 'Left')

    def go_right(self):
        screen.onkeypress(None, 'Right')

        xcor = int(self.xcor())
        ycor = int(self.ycor())

        if (xcor + TILE_SIZE, ycor) not in walls:
            self.setheading(0)
            self.setx(xcor + TILE_SIZE)

        screen.onkeypress(self.go_right, 'Right')

def setup_maze(level):
    ''' plot out the map as a maze in turtle '''

    # declare the limits for the entire maze
    maze_height, maze_width = len(level), len(level[0])

    # get the center point for each maze
    center_horizontal_point = (maze_width + 1) / 2
    center_vertical_point = (maze_height + 1) / 2

    start = finish = None

    for y in range(maze_height):
        for x in range(maze_width):
            character = level[y][x]  # get the character at each coordinate

            # calculate the screen x, y coordinates
            screen_x = int((x - maze_width) * TILE_SIZE + center_horizontal_point * TILE_SIZE)
            screen_y = int((maze_height - y) * TILE_SIZE - center_vertical_point * TILE_SIZE)
            maze.goto(screen_x, screen_y)

            if character == 'X':
                maze.fillcolor('grey')
                walls.append((screen_x, screen_y))  # add coordinates for the wall
            else:
                paths.append((screen_x, screen_y))  # add coordinates for the path

                if character == 'e':
                    maze.fillcolor('red')
                    finish = (screen_x, screen_y)
                elif character == 's':
                    maze.fillcolor('green')
                    start = (screen_x, screen_y)
                else:
                    maze.fillcolor('white')

            maze.stamp()

    return start, finish

grid = []  # create a grid list to store the labels while reading from the txt file

with open("map02.txt") as file:  # open the txt file and read contents and append it to maze
    for line in file:
        grid.append(line.strip())

screen = Screen()  # extract the Screen class from turtle
screen.setup(700, 700)  # set the size of the turtle window

sprite = ManualSprite()  # instantiate a Sprite instance

walls = []  # walls coordinate list
paths = []

maze = Wall()  # instantiate the Wall class
path = Path()

start, finish = setup_maze(grid)

sprite.setheading(0)
sprite.goto(start) # move the sprite to the start location

screen.listen() # allow turtle to detect key press and respond to it
screen.mainloop()
```

I've tossed comments that simply echo the obvious.  Also, your logic didn't take into account the imprecision of floating point coordinates which makes them difficult to compare -- I've converted those comparisons to `int`.